# Setting DropDownListFor default text MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, and am trying to do something that should be easy, but it is eluding me.  I am using a DropDownListFor in a partial view to display a list of product names.  That part works fine.  What I am having trouble with is setting the initial value of the DropDownListFor to display "Select one".  The code I am working with is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductData, "ProductId", "Name"), "---Select one---", new {  htmlAttributes = new { @id = "ProductName" } });
```

The controller which sets the ViewBag is as follows:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(int quoteId, int quoteDetailId)
        {
            var items = db.Products.ToList();
            ViewBag.ProductData = items;

            ViewData["QuoteId"] = quoteId;
            ViewData["QuoteDetailId"] = quoteDetailId;
            return PartialView("EditQuoteDetail", new QuoteDetail { QuoteId = quoteId, QuoteDetailId = quoteDetailId, ProductId = 1, ProductName = " ", Amount = 1, ListPrice = 0, Discount = 0, Price = 0 });
        }
```

Once I hit the dropdown arrow on the DropDownListFor, "Select one" appears at the top of the list.  But when the DropDownListFor is first displayed, the first product name appears in the box, instead of "Select one".  How can I fix this?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're setting the initial value of `ProductId` to 1, which is probably a valid value in your select list. That will cause the matching option to be selected when the model is bound in the view.

Comment: Just omit `ProductId = 1` so it uses the default and the null label option ("Select one") is selected. And why are you setting `ViewData` values when they are already in your model?

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks!  I used the ViewData because I thought I needed to set the values of QuoteId and QuoteDetailId.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a value for the id property in your model:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(int quoteId, int quoteDetailId)
{
    var items = db.Products.ToList();
    ViewBag.ProductData = items;

    return PartialView("EditQuoteDetail", new QuoteDetail { QuoteId = quoteId, QuoteDetailId = quoteDetailId, ProductId = 0, ProductName = " ", Amount = 1, ListPrice = 0, Discount = 0, Price = 0 });
}
```